# Can't post to Sqlite Database after deploying .Net Core 2.0 and Angular4 to AWS

Tags: angular, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, .net-core-2.0

After a successful deployment of the Angular 4.0 Universal & ASP.NET Core 2.0 advanced starter-kit to Elastic Beanstalk (here: http://asp2017-prod.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/home), I noticed that the Rest API Demo section successfully returns a GET request with users, but POST and DELETE requests result in a 500 error. After attaching a remote debugger to the process, I get the error that the database is read only. I remoted over and set the IIS_IUSRS role to the .DBA file and restarted the instance.

Now I get the following error: SQlite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

The GET requests still work. Only POST, PUT and DELETE fail.

For comparison, this exact deployment works fine on Azure. (here: http://asp201720180103014313.azurewebsites.net/users)

Comment: a 500 error can be produced by several reason, e.g. your sqlite database can be locked, or your database don't have a table, etc .check the response and give us some more information for help you (the response can be a html that show the error)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question here.

To all future AWS developers for Elastic Beanstalk: These instances are specifically designed to be immutable. The reason the database reads as cannot be opened or is read-only is because these instances abhor write changes due to their ephemeral nature. Simply put, flat file DB's are not acceptable on an EB instance. Use something else, or spin up a virtual server.